# Rails - Inject text/ads after n paragraphs in Red Carpet markup content

Tags: ruby-on-rails, markup

Using Rails 3.2.11 and RedCarpet

I have a website with a lot of articles with about 5-6 paragraphs, written with RedCarpet markup language. I am not sure if me using RedCarpet is actually important in this case.

In my code I load the text from the database with this code:

> markdown(@article.content)

At the moment, if I want to put Google Adsense-ads into the text all I can do is either do it manually in each article or put it before or after the article. I would, however, like to have an ad after the 2nd paragraph.

Is there a gem or similar that could handle this? I would like to use:

> markdown(@article.content).inject(, )